# Convex problem with multiple global optima

Tags: reference-request, convex-analysis, convex-optimization

I am searching for a reference, preferably with a figure, of the consensus [here](https://www.researchgate.net/post/Why_are_optimal_solutions_found_at_boundary_points_Can_the_solution_be_within_the_feasible_region), which I sum up with the following quote from the cite:

"To make a clear summary of points already raised: In linear and convex optimization, where all equations and inequalities and functions are linear and convex and admissible domains are polytopes or convex sets, then the set of optimal points always contains corners of the boundary. It may contain entire facetts of the boundary, but a corner point is guaranteed."

Comment: The claim is correct only if the objective is linear. But the quote seems to be considering all of convex optimization. So I can't see how it is true. For instance, consider $f(x)=x^Tx$ subject to $\|x\|_\infty \leq 1$. The optimal point is the origin, which is not on the corner or any facet.

Answer (score -1):

It is almost true. If the problem is **bounded**, then there is always a vertex with optimal value. You can look at Theorem 10 and Corollary 11 in Karloff *Linear Programming*.

The Wikipedia article on [linear programming](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_programming) gives some pictures and examples too.

Comment: The solution _includes_ a vertex in the polytopic case, but it can be _more_ than just a vertex.

Comment: I agree, I guess it depends on what you mean by *solution*. To me, any feasible point with minimum value of the cost is a solution so there is always a solution on a vertex (there may well be other points). I'll edit my answer to make that clearer.

Comment: Right, but the OP talks about the "set of optimal points" so I think the distinction matters. That said, the quote is wrong, as I'm reading it... ;-)

Comment: As long as the problem is bounded, tt is true that the set of optimal points always contains a vertex; no?

Comment: If the objective function is linear, yes. But not if it is nonlinear; see my comment above.

Comment: Also, note that "corner point" is more general than "vertex". For example, the unit sphere $\|x\|_2\leq 1$ has no vertices but it does have corner points; indeed, every point on the boundary is a corner point.